# Vscode experimental decorators warning in inline javascript inside php file

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Laravel project using Blade templates and in some *.blade.php files i have  script tags  with some javascript and the @json decorator that give me warnings.

What I've tried and it didn't work:

- I have enable experimental decorators in vscode user settings
- create jsconfig.json to enable experimental decorators
- I have already "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true in my settings.json

Seems like all this solutions is for .js or .ts files...not for php files

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the literal warning text?

Comment: The warning text is: "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning."